# Should I use a cost matrix or an F2-score?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, supervised-learning

I'm currently building a classification model in which a false negative is twice as bad as a false positive.  That is, the cost matrix looks like (where a leading $P$ means "predicted" and a leading $T$ means "true"):

$$\begin{matrix}& TP & TN \\PP & 0 & 1 \\ PN & 2 & 0.\end{matrix}$$

The class imbalance is 2:1.

With these costs in mind, should I be looking to use a cost matrix with some other metric (like AUC or F1 score) to weigh the false positives as worse, or should I be using an $F2$ score, which weighs recall as being twice as important as precision?

Comment: did you find an answer to this yet? I have the same issue but with a 1:20 relation